# Google Apps Script - can't set formula with concat

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I made an application with google drive and sheets api the problem is that the sheet has some formulas that has conflicts with the created api so I was forced to erase the formulas and write a little app script to autofill the formulas. I was following this [tutorial][1]. But as the formula has strings to concat it throws a syntax error. My code is here:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  ss.getRange("I2").setFormula(CONCAT("problem string";"\n";C2;"\n";F2));

}
```

Do i need to declare the string as a variable?

EDIT: i am also having problems when using the \n new line character
[1]: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCBtsQGtzoQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Issues:

- [setFormula](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulaformula) accepts a string but you are passing `CONCAT` which is not defined nor it is a built in JavaScript method. To make it a string directly, you can use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).
- also your formula is wrong because `CONCAT` can concatenate only `2` strings, not `5`. You need to use [CONCATENATE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094123?hl=en).

### Solution:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  ss.getRange("I2").setFormula(`CONCATENATE("problem string";"\n";C2;"\n";F2)`);
}
```

**Output:**

[image: output]